# Same EFI System Partition for Dual Boot Windows&Ubuntu in Different Drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I installed Ubuntu alongside with my Windows 10 in dual boot setup. I currently have Windows 10 in my 250GB SSD and installed Ubuntu 20.04 in my 500GB SSD with something else option. I created home,root and swap partitions only on installation. On startup, I noticed both of them shown on my primary(250GB) SSD. They share the same ESP even they are seperate drives. Would that cause any problem? Should I seperate their ESPs?

Edit: In addition, if there would be any issues with one of the OSs, will that cause issue on the other one? If so, can I backup ESP and use it again?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no significant problem with one ESP for two operating systems across two drives. It’s probably the way most people set it up. An issue with one OS will almost certainly not impact the other unless the issue is to do with the ESP itself.

If you were to remove the drive with the ESP for some reason and tried to boot the other drive it will not work. There would be some benefit in having an ESP on both drives in the case of a disk failure one of the disks.

I have a system with an ESP on each drive and I simply copied the contents of one to the other and it worked fine (although this was systemd-boot not grub). You would have to make space for a small extra partition on the 500GB SSD to do this and probably reinstall grub to the new partition. That is one way to back it up although depending on how you backup your system as a whole you should have a backup there.